# Firebase Cloud Functions for devices with old SSL/TLS

Tags: firebase, ssl, google-cloud-functions, iot

I have an IoT device that makes http requests to a Cloud Function. This works ok until I setup a custom domain in Firebase. From the error I get, it looks like the device only supports SSL2, SSL3 and TLS 1.0. Now I'm trying to figure out a solution.

What are the possible solutions for this? Can I "enforce" a SSL/TLS version in a Cloud Function? Maybe I have to put a load balancer in front of the cloud function that supports these old cryptographic protocols?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to enforce the SSL/TLS version directly from the Cloud Functions.

Your best bet is to use the [GCP Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl) where you can set the SSL version to older cyphers.

This can be done by creating a [new Policy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/use-ssl-policies) and set `TLS 1.0 for Minimum TLS Version`

Comment: This seems like a reasonably work around. In my case, I ended up choosing to turn off ssl/tls entirely for the function I was using. This can be done in the GCP console, it's kind of hidden in the edit cloud function page.